# How do I convert my multiline outputs to 3x4

Tags: java

I have a problem where i need to print a year calendar when provided a year, and i can go month by month, but how would i convert my 1 month per line output to a 3 month per line output?

I've spent hours and hours fiddling with processing multiple lines at once and trying to input to arrays but for some reason i cant get any of it to work.

```
public static int day(int month, int day, int year) {
    int y = year - (14 - month) / 12;
    int x = y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400;
    int m = month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 2;
    int d = (day + x + (31 * m) / 12) % 7;
    return d;
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))
        return true;
    if (year % 400 == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 2000;
    String[] months = { "", // left empty so that months[1] = "January"
            "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
            "November", "December" };

    // days[i] = number of days in month i
    int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    for (month = 1; month < 13;) {

        // check for leap year
        if (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year))
            days[month] = 29;

        // print calendar header

            System.out.print("     " + months[month] + "   " + year + "   ");


        System.out.println();

            System.out.print("|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|");

        System.out.println();

        // print the calendar
        int d = day(month, 1, year);
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
            System.out.print("   ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= days[month]; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
            if (((i + d) % 7 == 0) || (i == days[month]))
                System.out.println();

        }
        month++;
    }
```

day(); simply outputs the first day of the month, for example, February of 2000 would output the equivalent of tuesday

my output currently looks like this

```
         January   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                   1 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 
     February   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
       1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 
     March   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
          1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
26 27 28 29 30 31 
     April   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                   1 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 
     May   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
    1  2  3  4  5  6 
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 
14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28 29 30 31 
     June   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
             1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 
     July   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                   1 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 
     August   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
       1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31 
     September   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                1  2 
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
     October   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31 
     November   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
          1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
26 27 28 29 30 
     December   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                1  2 
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31
```

Comment: With this approach it is not possible. This is because once you print out the line it is not possible to go back and change it. The only alternative I see is that you need to decide what you are going to print out across the entire line before printing it. It means that you will need to compute dates across 3 months and then print it out line by line rather than doing it one month at a time.

Comment: Wow, i tried to do it myself but it seems really hard, maybe you should create an array list, add the first row of the first, second and third months, fourth, fifth and sixth months... Then print everything as one line.